# Protractor tests are not running in firefox with directconnect true

Tags: angularjs, firefox, protractor, geckodriver

[config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BZjr.png)

I am unable to run my test in firefox with directconnect true. Please provide a solution

**Versions:**

```
Angular: 4
Protractor: 5.1.2
Selenium Standalone Server: 3.4.0
GeckoDriver: 0.18.0
Firefox Browser: 54.0
```

Comment: what error your facing?

Comment: [12:21:37] E/launcher - Unable to parse new session response: {"value": {"sessionId":"5c173e29-28af-4cf7-bc63-87fbacb33f9b","capabilities":{"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"54.0","moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"moz:processID":10653,"moz:profile":"/tmp/rust_mozprofile.24dSwCEp8yEP","pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platformName":"linux","platformVersion":"4.4.0-87-generic","rotatable":false,"specificationLevel":0,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"pageLoad":300000,"script":30000}}}}

Comment: Can you please post your config file?

Comment: exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    //directConnect:true,
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444',
    specs: ['spec4.js'],
    // capabilities: {
    //     browserName: 'chrome',
    //     chromeOptions: {
    //         args: [
    //             '--start-maximized'
    //         ]
    //     }
    // },
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox',
    }
};

Answer (score 0):

I modified your configuration file and use it as given below

exports.config =

{

framework: 'jasmine',

directConnect:true,

specs: ['spec4.js'],

capabilities: {

browserName: 'firefox',

}
 };

Comment: Not working...same result...No url is being passed into the browser..... E/launcher - Unable to parse new session response:.....E/launcher - WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response:

Comment: @JemiArtista,  
directConnect is not working with Firefox 52+ and Protractor 5.1.1. (angular/protractor#4253) Have you tried with a standalone version of webdriver-manager to eliminate the directConnect problems?                              Try with Selenium Port Address seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'.

Comment: Yes, working with standalone version...but facing problem with "MouseMove" functionality in firefox.

Comment: need the solution with directConnect= true and also with protractor 5.1.2.not 5.1.1. you need to provide a solution with directConnect but not the alternatives.

Comment: Try with java script executor for mouse hover action

Comment: can you write the code by using javascript executor with which MouseMove can be done @ Parthi